# Sencha touch couresel items float one above the other

Tags: sencha-touch-2, carousel

My carousel is rendering weird, it doesnt load items horizontally it loads them one above the other. It looks like this: http://postimage.org/image/3tisqjl9n/

Is it because i make a carousel inside of a formpanel ?
Here you can see my code:

```
config: {
    title: 'More Info',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            id:"moreInfo",
            items: [
                {   
                    id: 'moreContent',
                    tpl: [
                        '<div style="border-bottom 1px solid black">',
                            '<h2 style="margin-bottom:5px;text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold">Project: {project}</h2>',
                        '</div>'
                    ].join(''),
                },
                { 
                    xtype: 'carousel',
                    defaults: { cls: 'card'},
                    direction: 'horizontal',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    directionLock: true,
                    items:[
                        {
                            html: "<img src='image1'>",
                        },
                        {
                            html: "<img src='image2'>",
                        },
                        {
                            html: "<img src='image3'>",
                        },
                        {
                            html: "<img src='image4'>",
                        },

                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    defaults: {
                        labelWidth: '35%'
                    },  
                    title: 'Receipts',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'takePicture',
                            padding: '10px',
                            text: 'Taka a picture'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'Price',
                            name: 'price'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'Vendor',
                            name: 'vendor'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'receiptSave',
                    padding: '10px',
                    ui:'confirm',
                    text: 'Save'
                },
            ]
        },

    ],
},
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I tried it in senchafiddle and only add the height config to the carousel: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#js9gQ

Comment: Ur fiddle looks just like my app is soposed to. maybe my css is corrupt or something, i will check it out. Tnx for ur time

Comment: Maybe you can post your CSS too and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I dont add any css, im only using the default one. This is how it renders on my phone and desktop http://postimage.org/image/clck2bfun/

Comment: Try to set layout of carousel from 'fit' to 'card' and set its absolute height (try one which is smaller than the one of the pictures) like in the senchafiddle.

Comment: It doesnt work but it is better than before :) Now when you come to the last image and then go back it works just fine, but before you come to the last image carousel looks like i posted on the image above.

Comment: tnx for your help my css was some weird one. But can I somehow set the height of carousel to auto ?

Comment: Auto in height? what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I would like carousel to take the height of the image displaying.

Comment: Have a look at the component in Chrome debugger, maybe you can find out what part in css have to be changed